# Spi MOSI connected to gnd

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, spi

Hello iam looking at someone's pcb design and they have the MOSI pin connected to one of the IC's GND pin.The spi interface pins are not being used at all on this IC except the MOSI to GND.

Another weird thing is the MOSI trace isnt a direct trace to GND.It looks like there is a 0805 smd footprint with one pad connected to the MOSI pin and the GND pin connected to the other.

It looks like a zero ohm resistor could have just been put in that smd foot print.Instead they soldered the two pads together to connect MOSI to GND.Firstly why connect only the MOSI pin to GND?
Thanks

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20001801h.pdf

Comment: What is the IC?  Link to datasheet?

Comment: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20001801h.pdf

Comment: You're going to need to include a schematic and/or a photo of the board you're looking at. There is definitely not enough information in this post to determine design intent.

Comment: There's no MOSI in that datasheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practice not to leave input pins floating. If an input pin is floating, then it is possible for enough charge to build up on the pin for the input to be between power and ground. In this case, both the NFET and PFET input transistors can be turned on causing excessive current consumption through the transistors from power to ground. In your case you mention that the SPI is not used; MOSI (SI) is a Slave Input. I would also expect to see the SCK input connected to ground, and SPI Chip Select CS pulled high.

The pins of many IC's these days may be configured as a pin for many peripherals. If it is possible - usually during development- that the pin might accidentally be configured as an output, I recommend connecting the pin to ground through a 1k Ohm resistor. This still pulls the pin to a hard low, but will limit current protecting the IC in the event they pin is erroronously configured as an output and driven high.